# Approximating Pi (Langtangen, Exercise 3.18.)

Tags: python

I am currently learning python and I've encountered a problem with my code. It runs properly when I put in values for the range but when I try to put a variable I'm returned with an error.

```
Instructions I was given:
```

> The value of 
>   π
>   equals the circumference of a circle with radius 1/2. Suppose we approximate the circumference by a polygon through 
>   n+1
>   points on the circle. The length of this polygon can be found using the pathlength function from the previous exercise. Compute 
>   n+1
>   points 
>   (xi,yi)
>   along a circle with radius 1/2 according to the formulae

Error :

> File "[user code]", line 16, in 
>   NameError: name 'N' is not defined

Here is my code:

```
import math

from math import cos
from math import sin
from math import pi
def pathlength (x,y):
    L = 0
    for i in range (1,len(x)):
        L += math.sqrt((x[i] - x[i-1])**2 + (y[i] - y[i-1])**2)
    return L

def circle_pts(N):
    x = [0.5 * cos(2*pi*i/N) for i in range (N+1)]
    y = [0.5 * sin(2*pi*i/N) for i in range (N+1)]
    return x,y

approx_pi = [2**k for k in range (0,N+1)]

for N in approx_pi:
    x,y = circle_pts(N)
    approx = pathlength (x,y)
    print ('For %4d points on the circle, pi approximates to %.8f giving and error \
and error of %.8f' % (N, approx, pi - approx))
```

Comment: What do you think `N` is in `approx_pi = [2**k for k in range (0,N+1)]`?

Comment: Take a look at that ^ and the dupe and figure it out.

Comment: I have encountered a different problem and would appreciate it if you could reopen the query. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Please open a new question if you have a different query.